# Preserve original time value in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I need to select the earliest date and time, as well as the latest date and time from a group of rows in Power BI into a new column. However, when I use the MAX() or MIN() functions, I lose the time part of the original column (e.g., if the original value is 8/22/2018 10:39:00, the new value in the new column after applying MAX() is 8/22/2018 00:00:00).

Answer (score 1):

The `MAX` and `MIN` functions do not strip the time component. However, you need to make sure your new column is using a Date/Time data type rather than a Date type. Check that it is set properly under the Modeling tab:

[image: Modeling Tab]

Answer (score 0):

The LASTDATE and FISTDATE functions of dax can be also used to get the datetime values as min and max of a column with the date and time format. Can check an example of FISTDATE function on link (
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/query-bi/dax/firstdate-function-dax)